# Adding 0 after number and after decimal using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where I should allow 0 after number and decimal number

Is there a way that I can let the user to show the number in `$1.0` in this way and decimal number like `$1.5` in `$1.50` using JavaScript.

I tried this but it did not help me

```
addZero: function (q)
    {
        alert(q);
        //var a = ("0" + q).slice(-2);
        return q;
    }
```

But I don't know how to add 0 after number and after decimal number using JavaScript.

Comment: You are looking for `.toFixed(1)`, which will set the number to the "tens" place.  `5..toFixed(1)` will result in "5.0"

Comment: But if i want to show $1.5 in $1.50 way...using .toFixed method i can only able to add 0 to whole number but for decimal number i cant get $1.50